# Verify identity $\frac{\cos \theta}{1+ \sin \theta} = \frac{1 - \sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am using the difference of squares to verify the identity; $$\Big( \frac{1-\sin \theta}{1-\sin \theta} \Big)\Big(\frac{\cos\theta}{1 + \sin \theta}\Big) = \frac{1 - \sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$$

There is the algebra principle of multiplying by $1$.  One times anything will always equal itself.  I was wondering if this is the explanation that permits me to multiple $ \frac{1-\sin \theta}{1- \sin \theta}$ to the left side but not the right?

The idea of multiplying by one seems weak because the left side of the equation no longer resembles itself after the multiplication is done.

It also seems like I am multiplying by the reciprocal.  I have not looked as deep into that idea yet.

Here is the rest of the solution
$$\frac{\cos \theta(1-\sin \theta)}{1 -\sin^2 \theta}$$

Pythagorean identity of $\cos^2\theta= 1- \sin\theta$ $$\frac{\cos \theta(1-\sin\theta)}{\cos \theta(\cos \theta)}$$

After canceling out the $\cos \theta$ from the top and bottom the left = the right.
$$\frac{ 1- \sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{1- \sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$$

Comment: Try to multiply the equation by $\cos\theta(1+\sin\theta)$.

Comment: So what is your question? As you mention, multiplying by 1 doesn't change the expression

Comment: @user While in this case, cross multiplying clearly shows how the identity is a rearranged Pythagorean identity, it'd be best in general to manipulate one side for these "verify identity" problems

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/510016/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3350633/42969

Comment: I think the book is asking me to make the left side of the equation equal to the right side of the equation.  In other words what can I do to the left side of the equation to get it into the form of $ \frac{1-sin \theta}{cos \theta}$.  I was wondering how can I only work on one side of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality between those fractions is equivalent to
$$
\cos^2\theta = (1-\sin \theta)(1+\sin \theta) = 1-\sin^2 \theta
$$
Does it ring a bell? :)

note: Not exactly equivalent because the initial equality is only defined when $\cos \theta \ne 0$ and $\sin \theta \ne -1$, but the proposed equality holds whenever all expressions are well defined.

Comment: I can see the identity and the reason why keeping the fraction helps to define the domain.  We can not divide by zero so those points are not in the domain.  Would you mind explaining why the difference of squares works?  If I am taking the difference of squares on the left side shouldn’t I have to also repeat that on the right side?

Comment: This must be ok because the equation strats out as an equality, remains an equality while using the difference of squares, and also ends as an equality.  Therefore I can add to one side and not the other as long as one side is equal to the other!  I hope that.’s right.

Comment: @Benp404 This is just putting everything on the LHS, reducing to the same denominator and forcing the numerator to be zero.